# Rails server failing to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boot

I'm struggling to get my rails server to boot.

I'm using Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3p429, rvm 1.21.1, and my gemfile is v2.03, on Ubuntu 12.04. I've updated using `rvm update --system`.

When I type `rails server`, I get the following backtrace:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support      /dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- java (LoadError)
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/pdf_ravager-0.1.0/lib/pdf_ravager/field_types/acro_form.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/pdf_ravager-0.1.0/lib/pdf_ravager/fields/text.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/pdf_ravager-0.1.0/lib/pdf_ravager/template.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/pdf_ravager-0.1.0/lib/pdf_ravager.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/user/Documents/cred/config/application.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've tried uninstalling rails and removing all gems, but I get a similar error message when I use `sudo gem uninstall rails`.

I did at one point follow this script (found here http://6brand.com/how-to-downgrade-rubygems.html) to downgrade rubygems, because it seems that updating was causing problems:

```
rubygems=`ruby --disable-gems -S gem which rubygems`
echo $rubygems
rm $rubygems
rm -rf `dirname $rubygems`/rubygems
```

Perhaps this caused corruption, but I subsequently reinstalled ruby and updated rubygems using rvm.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for replying! I did remove the pdf_ravager gem, as I'm not using JRuby, and then did a bundle install.   Now I'm getting the following backtrace...seems like he Psych gem, which must be a dependency, is causing issues:

```
/home/saasbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:246:in `block in visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Unknown alias: test (Psych::BadAlias)
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:246:in `fetch'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:246:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:264:in `block in revive_hash'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:258:in `each'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:258:in `each_slice'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:258:in `revive_hash'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:141:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:273:in `block in revive_hash'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:258:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:258:in `each_slice'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:258:in `revive_hash'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:141:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Mapping'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:238:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb:35:in `to_ruby'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:128:in `load'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/devise-2.0.5/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:42:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/Documents/cred/config/initializers/devise.rb:26:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/devise-2.0.5/lib/devise.rb:284:in `setup'
from /home/user/Documents/cred/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/user/Documents/cred/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/user/Documents/cred/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /home/user/Documents/cred/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/user/Documents/cred/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@anewhope/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

And here is the applicaion.rb file:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require 'net/http'

# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
# If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
# If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
# Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Cred
  class Application < Rails::Application
  # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
  # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
  # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

  # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
  # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

  # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
  # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
  # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

  # Activate observers that should always be running.
  # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

  # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
  # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
  config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'

  # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
  # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

  # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"

  # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
  config.filter_parameters += [:password]

  # Enable the asset pipeline
  config.assets.enabled = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Ensures that mass assignment error message is rendered
  config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

  # Forcing app not to access DB or load models when precompiling assets for Heroku
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  config.middleware.use "BraintreeInterceptor" if Rails.env.test?
  end
end
```

And here is the Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'faker'
gem 'will_paginate' 
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'wicked' 
gem 'devise','~>2.0.0'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'docusign_rest',:git => "git://github.com/torcido/docusign_rest"
gem 'multipart-post'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'shotgun'
gem 'braintree'
gem "json", "~> 1.8.0"
gem 'pdf-forms'
gem 'spreadsheet'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


# use Haml for templates
gem 'haml'

group :development do
  gem 'haml-rails'
end

# create Rails3 compatible generators for config file
gem 'rails3-generators'


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  gem 'hpricot'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
  gem 'slim' 
  gem 'haml2slim'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'pickle'
  gem 'launchy'          # a useful debugging aid for user stories
  gem 'pg'
  gem "rspec"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'cucumber-rails-training-wheels' # some pre-fabbed step definitions  
  gem "factory_girl"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem 'database_cleaner' # to clear Cucumber's test database between runs
end

# High Voltage gem from Thoughtbot. Rails engine for static pages: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage
gem 'high_voltage'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
  gem 'therubyracer',:require=>'v8'
end

gem 'jquery-rails',"~> 2.1.2"
```

Comment: It seems that you're trying to require a file/gem named java in /home/user/Documents/cred/config/application.rb. Can you show us your Gemfile and your application.rb file ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're running JRuby, you'll have to remove PDF Ravager from your gemfile (at least according to the [source code](https://github.com/abevoelker/pdf_ravager/blob/e5bb4a92c89c9d5d487017928a832480e0cdafe4/lib/pdf_ravager/ravager.rb)). [This](https://github.com/abevoelker/pdf_ravager/blob/e5bb4a92c89c9d5d487017928a832480e0cdafe4/lib/pdf_ravager/field_types/acro_form.rb) is the file trying to require `java`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a semi-solution: I manually removed the psych gem. I had to do so manually because the `gem uninstall` command was also failing.

So, I performed the following commands:

```
rm /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb
rm /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/psych.so
```

Now `rails server` and `gem uninstall` and `autotest` are working. Yay!

The reason I say semi-solution is that, when I run these commands, I get the following message up front:

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

However, after following the directions and installing libyaml and reinstalling ruby...I go back to the old Psych error backtrace!

So I'm happy to get back to coding my application, but I'm concerned about this apparently important missing gem. Any thoughts on getting a clean Psych gem installation?